# How to pass multiple SQLite3 istructions without writing separate .txt file?

Tags: sqlite

I developed a windows.bat file like this (file import.bat):

```
sqlite3 myDb.db<SQLTableTransfer.txt
```

This script is very simple, it simply run the sqlite3 shell command passing two parameters :

- the first parameter is the name of my db (myDb.db)
- the second parameter is a file name . The file SQLTableTransfer.txt has this content

  ```
  .open myDb.db

  .separator ;

  .import myCsv.csv mytable
  ```

Now I would like to avoid to write a separate .txt file. My goal would be to put all commands in the .bat file. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple `-cmd` options on the command line, as shown below. But note that you've already specified the database name on the command line, so you shouldn't use the .open command. What you *do* need is the `.mode` command.

```
sqlite3 -cmd ".mode csv" -cmd ".separator ;" -cmd ".import myCsv.csv mytable" myDb.db
```

It ignores any `-cmd .quit` command so if you want to exit from the sqlite shell, you'll need to add `<nul` at the end of the command instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can feed multiple commands through a pipe:

```
(echo .mode csv
 echo .separator ;
 echo .import myCsv.csv mytable) | sqlite3 myDb.db
```